# How to import a C# template in Visual Studio 2019 in a new projekt

Tags: templates, import, visual-studio-2019

I've created a new project and would like to import a C# project template
into it - but is does not work

I have a template in a zip file an expanded it in a folder
If i use project new I can not see choice to choose the file

I I use Project new file - I can not see a template file

If I use project from existing code - and give it a name
no files appears from the expanded template folder

How to do it?